# OSClass 404 error for location search

Tags: http-status-code-404, osclass

I installed OSClass and added some ads with specific locations (eg New York). I can see that against the location, there is a count of 1 indicating that there is one ad for that location, but when I click on the name of the region (New York) to access the add, a 404 Error page comes up that the page is not found. I am a new OSClass User, so please is there something I am missing? Shouldn't the hyperlink from the Region go directly to a list of ads posted in that region without error?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search result page, if there aren't results, return status code 404 (Not found), you can recalculate the location item stats via oc-admin -> tools -> Location stats

Answer (score 1):

open:

```
/oc-includes/osclass/controller/search.php
```

Search for:

```
if( count($aItems) === 0 ) {
```

Replace with:

```
if( count($aItems) === -1 ) {
```

Source(or for more information):

http://forums.osclass.org/3-1-x/3-1-1-search-bug-404-page-not-found/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it can be solved:

1. go to admin >Settings >Permalinks
2. For Page URL use `p/{PAGE_SLUG}`
3. For Category URL use `{CATEGORIES}`

> "Fix to this is using something that make the url different, for
>   example cat/{CATEGORIES} or page/{PAGE_SLUG} or {PAGE_SLUG}-{PAGE_ID}
>   ,...."
>
> The magic, not only can I all the categories URL without pre-path,
>   opening the locations also work now.

src: https://github.com/osclass/Osclass/issues/907

Answer (score 0):

Some times problem occurs while you install osclass in subdirectory that its name contain space.
Ex:
`C:/xampp/htdocs/Free Advertisement Scripts/OsClass/`

you must change it to:
**`/Free_Advertisement_Scripts/`**